# How to solve Unity error [13:14:09] in console?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[See error in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HRFT.png)

Version "2020.3.18f",
I have windows 10,
I just created a new project and didn't do anything ,
The errors kept showing.
Regards

Comment: Try to install another version of Unity.

Comment: Do you recommend any?

Comment: lol that's a timestamp. You should hit Clear and fix all remaining compiler errors. Then perhaps these empty errors will also go away. You should also click one of these errors and see if its stacktrace has any useful info.

Comment: @DamianPiszka it's the latest LTS version .. I wouldn't simply recommend o use another one ^^

Comment: @DamianPiszka thank you for your help i did what you told me and it worked(changed the version of the editor).

Answer (score 0):

1. Click one of these errors, it can show you the error in your code.
2. Try to install the latest LTS version